# Laravel 8.0 Blade nested @extends @section and @yield not working

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I have this `template.blade.php` with a path of `views/templates/template.blade.php` with the following code:

```
// template.blade.php


// some codes here

@include("templates.navigation.navigation")
@yield('header')
@yield('content')
@include('templates.footer.footer')

// some other codes here
```

Now, in my route, the `home.blade.php` (accessible at `views/home/home.blade.php`) was set as the landing page. The homepage needs to borrow a section of code (code for the floating buttons. Each floating button differs depending on the current page). Here's the code for the homepage:

```
// home.blade.php


@extends('templates.template')
@section('header')
    // some codes here
@endsection

@section('content')
    // some other codes here
    @yield('float-button-module-menu') // the code that needs to be accessed but doesn't work
@endsection
```

The `@yield('float-button-module-menu')` would be accessed at `views/templates/float-buttons/float-buttons.blade.php`. Here's the code for the said webpage:

```
// float-buttons.blade.php


@extends('home.home') // I suspect that I was wrong at declaring the name for the @extends here
@section('float-button-module-menu')
    // some codes inside the section that needs to be displayed
@endsection
```

To simplify the question, I need to access the `@section('float-button-module-menu')` from `float-buttons.blade.php` inside `home.blade.php`. I do not know the problem within the logic of this.

**EDIT** here's the full code for the sections inside `float-button.blade.php`:

```
// float-button.blade.php


@extends('home.home')
@section('float-button-module-menu')
<div class="d-flex flex-column position-fixed button button-float-position-buttom-left">
    <div class="button-float d-flex">
        <span class="fas fa-user-cog text-lg text-white align-self-center mx-auto"></span>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection

@section('float-button-anchor')
<div class="button-float d-flex">
    <span class="fas fa-arrow-up text-lg text-white align-self-center mx-auto"></span>
</div>
@endsection

@section('float-button-help')
<div class="button-float d-flex">
    <span class="fas fa-question text-lg text-white align-self-center mx-auto"></span>
</div>
@endsection

// list of buttons would be updated.
```

Comment: Do you call/view `float-buttons.blade.php` itself somewhere? Sounds like you want to `@include('float-buttons')` inside your `home.blade.php`

Comment: @brombeer I've tried `include('template.float-buttons.float-buttons')` without the `@section()` and `@extends()` inside `float-buttons.blade.php` but not `@include('float-buttons')`. Is there something wrong in how I declare the name inside `@include`?

Comment: No, that sounds right. Make sure your `float-buttons.blade.php` contains just the code you want to display, ditch the `@extends` and `@section` from it

Comment: if I'll ditch the `@extends` and `@section` inside `float-buttons.blade.php`, then how should I call `float-buttons.blade.php` inside `home.blade.php`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extending views is for when you call/view a blade file directly, for example via `return view('templates.float-buttons.float-buttons')`. Sounds like this is not what you are looking for. You'd want to `@include` the file in your `home.blade.php`. Make the following changes:

home.blade.php:

```
@extends('templates.template')
@section('header')
    // some codes here
@endsection

@section('content')
    // some other codes here
    @include('templates.float-buttons.float-buttons')
@endsection
```

float-buttons.blade.php:

```
<div>
  My Float Buttons Code
</div>
```

`float-buttons.blade.php` will just contain the code for your float buttons

---

#### Second part

You can pass parameters to `@include` when [including subviews](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#including-subviews). See if these changes suit your needs:

home.blade.php

```
@extends('templates.template')
@section('header')
    // some codes here
@endsection

@section('content')
    // some other codes here
    @include('templates.float-buttons.float-buttons', ['type' => 'anchor'])
@endsection
```

float-buttons.blade.php:

```
@if ($type == 'anchor')
<div class="button-float d-flex">
    <span class="fas fa-arrow-up text-lg text-white align-self-center mx-auto"></span>
</div>

@elseif ($type == 'help')
<div class="button-float d-flex">
    <span class="fas fa-question text-lg text-white align-self-center mx-auto"></span>
</div>

@else
{{-- if no type parameter is given --}}
<p>
  Parameter 'type' is required
</p>
@endif
```

You can then basically use `@include('templates.float-buttons.float-buttons', ['type' => 'anchor'])` or `@include('templates.float-buttons.float-buttons', ['type' => 'help'])` wherever you need it. And of course feel free to expand the list

---

Note: A more elegant solution imho would be to create single blade files for each of your cases ('float-buttons-anchor.blade.php`,` float-buttons-help.blade.php`...) and then include the file you need:`@include('templates.float-buttons.float-buttons-help')

Comment: The logic for this one is ok, but I need to access the `float button codes` as sections so that I could reuse **only** the sections that'll repeat within the system. I've tried the solution but it'll bloat my system

**edit** it won't bloat the system but I need to dynamically access the sections depending on the page.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this. Do you have multiple codes for float buttons and want to choose which to show?!

Comment: Still a little confused, sorry ;) If I understand you correct there are multiple sections inside float-buttons, you need to show a different section depending on the page you're on? Personally, I'd create _one_ template for each of those use cases and let `float-buttons.blade.php` handle which one to show. Could you maybe show what `float-buttons.blade.php` actually contains?

Comment: sureee take your timeee

Comment: Added the "Second part" section to my answer, see if that works for you.

Comment: I'll give you an update on this. gimme a second

Comment: this is a good approach! I could still dynamically edit the contents of my system. thanks!